# iOS: disconnected when in inactive state?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, background, connection

I'm analyzing the feasibility of an app. Just a question:

when the app brings from active state to inactive state (sleep or power button pressed) can I set a timer and request data using a remote http connection? I'm afraid that in inactive state the iOS closes all connections: there's a way to prevent this when in inactive state?

Thanks

**EDIT**

[In the official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1) I've read this:

> **Be prepared to handle connection
>   failures in your network-based
>   sockets**. The system may tear down
>   socket connections while your
>   application is suspended for any
>   number of reasons. As long as your
>   socket-based code is prepared for
>   other types of network failures, such
>   as a lost signal or network
>   transition, this should not lead to
>   any unusual problems. When your
>   application resumes, if it encounters
>   a failure upon using a socket, simply
>   reestablish the connection.

This means that in Inactive state iOS can tear down my connection? Thanks

Comment: Your quote from the docs is about background state, not inactive state. They are not the same by a long shot!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike when going to background, your application continues to run as normal in the inactive state.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}
```

Comment: To clarify the comment in the code (straight from an Xcode project template, by the way): although there are cases where disabling timers etc. makes sense when going inactive for the app developer, the system will not automatically do that.

Comment: But are you sure that connections are not interrupted in inactive state?

Comment: Not sure, but pretty confident. Try it and see!

Comment: Come to think of it: I'm sure. We have a lot of background communication running, which continues happily in inactive mode.